# MS Access: Property defined with 'Form' return type in a interface gives user-defined type not defined compilation error

Tags: ms-access, vba

Looking for help writing an interface that has a property (or function) that returns an object typed as a "Form" (e.g. Access.Form as the return type).

**Problem description:**

The following simple example code returns a "User-defined type not defined" error if I attempt to compile the project.

I_TestInterface:

```
Public Property Get MyForm() as Form
End Property
```

cls_TestClass:

```
Implements I_TestInterface

Public Property Get I_TestInterface_MyForm() as Form
End Property
```

This is the only code/objects in a otherwise blank Access-2016 database and asking VBA to **'compile' produces a "User-defined type not defined" error**.  No lines are highlighted, it simply won't compile.  Same occurs if replace 'Form' by "Access.Form"

My usecase is writing classes that wrap/hold a reference to a form internally - sometimes it is easiest to provide a reference to the underlying form so that consuming code can get at form properties without coding them all into the wrapper class.

**Steps taken:**

Lots of searches on 'user-defined type not defined' errors, in almost all cases this is due to a missing reference.  Does not seem applicable since can create a standard module and happy to compile if write a function with a Form return type there. (*)

There was one previous SO thread on similar 'ambiguous' 'user-defined type not defined' error but I can't find it again and it wasn't specific to the 'Form' type in MS-Access

Have a clumsy workaround of providing property that returns an Object type that consuming code just has to cast to a Form (e.g. public property get MyFormAsObjectThatCanBeCastToForm() as Object).

(*).  Possible clue? - if I just change the return types to object, the code still won't compile.  I need to exit and use the 'de-compile' start up switch when relaunch Access.  Then the above code with Object used as a return type is happily compiled.

**Question / request:**

Before I start re-installing Office, can others reproduce this?

Has anyone experienced this before?  Developed a solution?

Thanks
PAHTDC

Comment: No repro here (up-to-date Access 365). I'd add a form to your database, as a test. Forms are a bit odd, since the `Form` object actually is an interface, and each form that has a module has it's own class named `Form_FormName`.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I am also Access 2016 via Office 365.  Original problem was in large multiform db, I will try your suggestion and see if any difference in the simple db.  I wonder also if I have some older version of Office with interfering references, just seems strange that effect only seen for class module used as an interface, fortunately it is happy to compile with class module used as class and Form as a return type of a property / function.